# Patches of particles (hair) on a plane following noise

Tags: node-editor, particles, hair

I'm trying to make underwater reeds for a scene in Blender cycles.

I have my reeds textured and ready, I'm using a particle system as a hair type and I've set it up so the "grass" covers my floor plane.

My problem is the grass is spread evenly across the plane. I want them to be in patches, clumped together and have the floor visible where they're absent.

A solution in my head would be for the particles to follow a noise node, tightened up using a colour ramp but I cant seem to figure this out, if it's at all possible?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method I would use to clump the vegetation together is by tweaking the 'radius' value in the particle's children tab. Note that children type must be set to 'Simple'.

[image: 3d viewport radius]
[image: Children menu]

This is the most simple and easy way to achieve the 'bush' look, but if you want more freedom and customization possibilities, a density texture is the way to go!

For example: I'm using a cloud texture to control where the hair can grow and where not.

[image: texture 3d view] 
[image: clouds and ramp]

For this example I'm using a cloud texture, but you can obviously paint a texture by hand and gain 100% control.

Make sure to check the influence of your texture:
[image: density check]

And assign it in the particle system as well:
[image]

A fundamental difference between these methods is that by using a texture, you're actually 'cutting' out portion of your scattered hair. By using the radius option under the children's panel, you control where the hair-particles are going to be scattered. So your amount of particles in the settings will be higher when using a texture.

Comment: It's not perfect but it's the best I've come across. Thank you for taking the time to explain that